# Porting iOS app to Android, crossplatforming with phonegap a better option?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile

I will need to develop a mobile application for my website for both iOS and Android.

Now I'm wondering, would using phonegap be a good idea to accelerate the process since it use html5 no matter the platform. I was currently planning on writing a native iOS app and then rewriting a "copy" for Android.

Furthermore, I would like the applications to have a native app feel, aka a feel that is native to the applications itself first and then to be compliant with the platform its running on. I've heard bad things about mobile apps that feels like a web app, that they're often unworthy of an app in the first place.

So would using html5 as a base for the application be a good idea? Otherwise are there any other trick in order to code for iOS and Android at the same time will giving the apps a feel that is native to my website in the first place before the OS its running on.

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question.  You can either go phonegap html5 or native.  If you want it to feel native, you have to write native.  If you want quick development and don't mind that it feels like a webpage, then go phonegap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your options pretty clear.
Try going native as the feeling of the app is way better(Remember facebook before being native).

Comment: I was halfway convinced, now I fully am, thank for the feedback :)